# How can I load debug-symbols for a running process?

Tags: gcc, gdb, debug-symbols

I have an C-application which runs on many machines and from time to time an instance makes issues and behaves weird. Unfortunately, this happens almost never. These prod-instances are compiled with heavy optimizations (`-march=XXX -Ofast`) and do not include any debug-symbols, so I cannot easily attach a debugger to analyze their state.

But I thought it should be possible to compile the application again with the same flags plus `-g3` and then I can load it in gdb with `symbol-file application_executable_with_debug_symbols`. However, if I do that then breakpoints never trigger.

Is there another way to attach a debugger to a running application and loading debug-symbols? Or is there something (obvious) which I do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Afaik it is not something possible.. Using your new elf/exe with debug symbols to debug an exisiting elf/exe without symbols. The best you could do is to identify the context/events/etc. which triggers bad behavior and then reproduce it within the debugger using the elf with debug symbols ..

Comment: The obvious question is, why did you not build your application with debug symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to build the application *with* debug symbols, keep the resulting binary for debugging, but run `strip -g app.debug -o app.release` and run the stripped binary in production.

When you find a misbehaving instance, you can copy the full-debug version to target machine, and run `gdb -ex 'attach $PID' app.debug`. Voila: you have full debug symbols.

---

The most likely reason that compiling the application again didn't work is that you got a new binary with different symbols (compare `nm app.debug` vs. `nm app.release`), and the most likely reason for *that* (if using GCC) is that you omitted some of the optimization flags used to build `app.release`, or you used slightly different sources -- you *must* use exactly the same flags (and add `-g`) and exactly the same sources for any hope of success with that approach.